# ¿Por qué se usa subjuntivo en "Y es una coincidencia que haya mencionado a Dumas"?

Tags: subjuntivo

Después de un capítulo de "El club Dumas" de Arturo Pérez-Reverte, ese escritor me tiene captado por su estilo (de momento). Él es muy artístico con el lenguaje, usando por ejemplo "Hace mal" por "you're mistaken". Este modismo es nuevo para mí. Después de traducirlo al inglés, muchas veces necesito buscar la definición de muchas palabras de mi propia lengua.

Pero, ¿qué regla se usa o entra en juega para que necesite el subjuntivo aquí?

> Y es una coincidencia que haya mencionado a Dumas.

Creo que es un complemento causativo: Aquí, el sujeto es la coincidencia y el verbo "hacer" es implicado: así la coincidencia hace que yo haya mencionado a Dumas.

Comment: Isabel Allende, Arturo Pérez-Reverte, Luis Sepúlveda, Federico García Lorca, Miguel Delibes... tus preguntas son un apasionante recorrido por la lengua española a través de grandes autores :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se usa el subjuntivo cuando calificamos de forma subjetiva o juzgamos alguna cosa de forma emotiva, o bien cuando imponemos una razón por la que alguna cosa tiene lugar.  A veces es difícil distinguir y de hecho muchas veces hay fuertes solapamientos entre ellos.  Pero para darte algunas oraciones parecidas:

> Es normal que … [subjuntivo]
>   Es común que … [subjuntivo]
>   Es una coincidencia que … [subjuntivo]
>   Es un milagro que … [subjuntivo]

Puede que la subjetividad aquí sea más evidente cuando invertimos el valor y vemos lo fuerte que podría ser el juzgamiento:

> Es abnormal que … [subjuntivo]
>   Es poco común que … [subjuntivo]
>   Es por X razón que … [subjuntivo]
>   Es una tragedia que … [subjuntivo]

Incluso es posible en cosas que normalmente emplearían indicativo, como *es obvio que …* (cuando esta calidad de ser obvio es algo subjetivo —de punto de vista personal con el entendimiento de que otros pueden opinar diferente— y menos objetivo).

Comment: hmm. Parece que puede usar subjuntivo en casi cualquier construction "es + adjectivo + que" como expresión impersonal porque quién sabe si es cierto u opinión en la mente de otro. Sin revisar una lista grammatica hubiera adivinado que el escritor no quería indicar valoración, opinion o incertidumbre aquí. Pero estoy de acuerdo. Creo que gramaticalmente este es la razón

Comment: Bueno, creo que en el ejemplo que proveíste, vemos tanto una causa (la coincidencia (no) lo causó) como una valorización.  Ambas pueden implicar el subjuntivo.  A pesar de que en muchos casos por alguna razón u otra se puede usar una u otra forma, es cierto que muchos adjetivos o sustantivos en la construcción impersonal «es X que…» suelen favorecer un modo en particular, un valor por omisión digamos.

Comment: Es acertado. Después de recibir una respuesta siempre reconozco la explicación pero no sé por qué antes no me la daba cuenta. :)

Comment: @guifa Sólo no estoy de acuerdo con "Es por X razón que + subjuntivo". Esa construcción se usa con indicativo.